# HTML5 geolocation API in various browsers

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have a problem using geolocation API in Firefox and IE. 
Every time the page is loaded that browsers show a message asking to allow defining my location. So I have to press "I allow" every time I navigate through site pages. The users of our site complain of this situation, because it's annoying.

Is there any way to avoid showing this message? Maybe I should use another geolocation API?

Comment: This is a browser security issue. Individual users can adjust their browser settings to always allow geolocation, but it's not something you can do programatically.

Comment: _“The users of our site complain of this situation, because it's annoying.”_ – then those users are complaining about their own stupidity – _both_ IE and Firefox offer the option to _always_ allow GeoLocation for the current site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a code problem. It's a browser problem.
It depends what you require your location for... If GPS for mobile apps the following won't help.

I have used the IP to work out location though this is only useful to find 'country' rather than city as such...

I have recently done this in PHP . Using full PHP though requires PHP add on 'GEOIP'

```
<?php
//Get users IP address
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
//Get 2 letter country code from IP
$country = geoip_country_code_by_name('$ip');
//If successful...
if ($country) {
//Write the name of the country 
echo 'This host is located in: ' . $country;
}?>
```

This will write 2 letter country code.
More information here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php

Hope this is useful for you, depending on what you are aiming to achieve this may be helpful to you.

As it isn't always successful it's worth nothing to put a 'fallback' default location should it not be retrievable.

Answer (score 1):

**Impossible**.  This is meant for **user's [PRIVACY POLICY](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/legal/privacy/firefox.html)**.

> **Geolocation** support is opt-in. That means your browser will never force you to reveal your current physical location to a remote server.
>   The user experience differs from browser to browser.

Which is known as [*Location-Aware Browsing*](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/)

> Source from [**DiveIntoHTML5**](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html#divingin)
>
> **Q:** Geolocation sounds scary. Can I turn it off?
>
> **A:** Privacy is an obvious concern when you’re talking about sharing your physical location with a remote web server. The geolocation API
>   explicitly states: “User Agents must not send location information to
>   Web sites without the express permission of the user.” In other words,
>   sharing your location is always opt-in. If you don’t want to, you
>   don’t have to.

This is handled differently in each browsers, yet common in theory.

But you can handle it wisely using [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/)

```
function get_location() {
  if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
  } else {
    // no native support; maybe try a fallback?
  }
}
```